Inkscape: crop identical segments across several images
Say we import two png images of identical pixel size in INKSCAPE and we also want to crop (set clip) the identical region in both images. How can we effectively do this?
My current workflow:

Placing both images in two (empty) layers
Manually checking the X,Y position of the pics is identical across both layers
Placing a rectangle in the layers
Manually checking the X,Y position of the rectangles is equalacross both layers

This works, but it is probably not the most efficient solution.

You don't really need to use layers or check the X and Y co-ordinates either. Seems overly complicated.  Try this instead:

Import one of the images, and draw the clipping rectangle and place it where you want it

Select both image and shape, and duplicate using Ctrl+D, and click and drag it to a different location

Import the second image and move it into place using snapping

Move the image to the bottom of the stack using End and select and delete the old image.


Then obviously apply the clipping masks to each image.
